# Application Load Balancer in front of Network Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-balancing, amazon-vpc

I have a VPC with a public and a private subnet. I want my auto scaling applications to live in the private subnet, so I'll need to access them via a load balancer in the public subnet. These applications also need to talk to each other internally.

I'm trying to use Elastic Beanstalk to create an internal network load balancer in my private subnet, which is pointing to my applications in the private subnet. Then I have manually created a public application load balancer in my public subnet. But it seems that my application load balancer is struggling to route to my network load balancer.

Is this a reasonable set up? I've seen lots of examples of a public facing network load balancing which is pointing to an internal application load balancer, but not the other way around. I've been able to get that to work but I can't redirect http to https at the network load balancer which is why I'd prefer it the other way around. If nothing else I'm thinking to have CloudFront in front of a public, network load balancer in front of a private network load balancer, and then handle the TLS and redirect from CloudFront instead.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the internal private load balancer? Your public load balancer can route traffic to your instances in the private subnets. Your internal instances can still talk to each other through your VPC.

Comment: @littleforest I think I need a private load balancer because I have multiple applications in the VPC which are auto scaling and need to speak to each other. I don't think I an make a direct connection between them because they are auto scaling. Please correct me if I'm wrong or if you have any alternative ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Your applications should be able to talk to each other in the private subnet through security group configurations. The load balancer would be irrelevant.

Comment: Yes they would be able to talk to each other, but if I have application A with an auto scaling group to spawn three instances, how will application B distribute the load between them without a load balancer?

Comment: Maybe I am confused about your setup. Why is application B responsible for distributing load for Application A?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a reasonable set up? I've seen lots of examples of a public facing network load balancing which is pointing to an internal application load balancer, but not the other way around.

Unfortunately no, that is not a reasonable setup, because it is not supported by AWS. An application load balancer can not forward traffic to another load balancer.

It's unclear from your description why you need a load balancer pointing at another load balancer at all. Your backend service can belong to multiple target groups, so multiple load balancers can forward traffic directly to your service. In other words, the public load balancer can forward traffic directly to your private services, without going through the private load balancer.

Comment: Thanks Mark. The reason for having two load balancers is because my understanding is the load balancer can't have both a public and a private IP. Since I need to access it both internally and externally.

If that is correct, would it be sensible to have a public load balancer and a private load balancer which are both pointing to the same target group?

Comment: A target group can't belong to multiple load balancers. But a server can belong to multiple target groups. Hence my recommendation to assign the servers to multiple target groups/load balancers.

Comment: And yes, it's common to do this so that you have a private load balancer for communication within the VPC, and a public load balancer for public traffic.